Hamburger menu freezing on one view only in Release build in MS Maui
I have a view in my AppShell that works totally fine in the Debug build. When I navigate to that view in the Release build using the hamburger menu, the application freezes on the screen that I was on prior to navigation. I can still use the hamburger menu, but I can't change the view.
All the other views are working as intended.
I have no errors in either Release or Debug. It appears that the screen I'm navigating to is never loading. OnAppearing and OnNavigatedTo aren't running.
Using Maui 8
for Win 10, Android
My appshell.xaml
<FlyoutItem Title="Tessitura Application">
        <ShellContent Title=""
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
                      Route="TessituraApp" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Environments">
        <ShellContent Title="Environments"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:EnvironmentsPage}"
                      Route="Environments" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Printers">
        <ShellContent Title="Printers"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:PrintersPage}"
                      Route="Printers" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    
    <FlyoutItem Title="Cash Drawer">
        <ShellContent Title="Cash Drawer"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CashDrawerSetupPage}"
                      Route="CashDrawerSetup" />
    </FlyoutItem>

Snippet of the view xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tessitura.AppWrapper.Models"
             x:Name="CashDrawerSetupPageName"
             x:Class="Tessitura.AppWrapper.Views.CashDrawerSetupPage">

    <Shell.TitleView>
        <VerticalStackLayout Padding="30,24,0,0">
            <Label FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="Center">Cash Drawer Setup</Label>
        </VerticalStackLayout >
    </Shell.TitleView>

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="30,30,30,30">
            <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Color="{StaticResource CustomGrayDE}" Margin="0,0,0,30" />

            <Label x:Name="windowsOnlyLabel" Text="Cash drawers are only supported in the Windows version of Sales Desk" IsVisible="False"/>

            <Label Text="BASIC SETTINGS"
                   Margin="0,0,0,15"
                   FontSize="15"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   TextColor="Black"
                   CharacterSpacing="0.8"/>
            <HorizontalStackLayout>


The code of CashDrawerSetupPage.xaml you provided is incomplete. during my test, if the page only contains Label and BoxView tags, the project can jump to the CashDrawerSetupPagethrough the hamburger menu normally. So please add more detailed code of theCashDrawerSetupPage.xamlfile and.cs` file.

Thanks for the comment, but it turned out to be a styling issue. One of the colors was incorrect, but no errors were being thrown.

Answer here on MS Maui forums
It turned out that a style I had was incorrect, which was breaking silently.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
